# AABB Tree Constructor function very very slow for std::vector

Tags: cgal

I found a phenomenon, CGAL AABB tree Constructor function is very very slow for `std::vector`.

Here is a minimal test code:

```
Point a(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Point b(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Point c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
std::vector<Triangle> triangles;    
for (size_t I=0;I<245000;I++)
{
    triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,b,c));
}
// constructs AABB tree
MyTree tree(triangles.begin(),triangles.end());
```

245000 Primitive, not built, run much slower. I find source:

```
template<typename Tr>
template<typename ConstPrimitiveIterator, typename ... T>
void AABB_tree<Tr>::insert(ConstPrimitiveIterator first,
                         ConstPrimitiveIterator beyond,
                         T ... t)
{
set_shared_data(t...);      
    while(first != beyond)
    {
        m_primitives.push_back(Primitive(first,t...));
        ++first;            
    }
m_need_build = true;
}
```

I suspect `vector` `push_back` function will reallocate memory, but I'm not sure is the reason, So I tried this code:

```
template<typename Tr>
template<typename ConstPrimitiveIterator, typename ... T>
void AABB_tree<Tr>::insert(ConstPrimitiveIterator first,
                         ConstPrimitiveIterator beyond,
                         T ... t)
{
set_shared_data(t...);
m_primitives.assign(beyond-first,first);//pre allcate promitives
size_t Index = 0;
    while(first != beyond)
    {           
        m_primitives[Index] = Primitive(first,t...);
        ++first;
        ++Index;
    }
m_need_build = true;
}
```

The problem solves! I need more advices, and I think this needs to be updated to CGAL source?

==================14-9-18 update =============== 
I make an simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "boost/timer/timer.hpp"
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_triangle_primitive.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Ray_3 Ray;
typedef K::Line_3 Line;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Triangle_3 Triangle;
typedef std::vector<Triangle>::iterator Iterator;
typedef CGAL::AABB_triangle_primitive<K, Iterator> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive> AABB_triangle_traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<AABB_triangle_traits> Tree;
int main()
{
    Point a(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Point b(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Point c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles;    
    for (size_t I=0;I<245000;I++)
    {
        triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,b,c));
    }
    #define TIMER_SECOND boost::timer::nanosecond_type(1000000000LL)

    auto first = triangles.begin();
    auto beyond = triangles.end();
    boost::timer::cpu_timer CountTimer;
    //Test 1    
    std::vector<Primitive> TestV1;
    CountTimer.start();
    while(first != beyond)
    {
        TestV1.push_back(Primitive(first));
        ++first;            
    }
    std::cout << "Test1 Time:" << CountTimer.elapsed().wall << std::endl;
    //Test 2
    first = triangles.begin();
    beyond = triangles.end();
    std::vector<Primitive> TestV2;
    CountTimer.start();
    TestV2.reserve(std::distance(first,beyond));
    while(first != beyond)
    {
        TestV2.push_back(Primitive(first));
        ++first;            
    }
    std::cout << "Test2 Time:" << CountTimer.elapsed().wall << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

in release mode:

Test1 Time:3426459
Test2 Time:926136

in debug mode:

Test1 Time:503719044580

Test2 Time:224280791

Comment: What do you mean by "very slow", "much slower" (than what?), "solves", etc? It is not clear from your description, but would a simple call `m_primitives.reserve(std::distance(first,beyond));` be enough? (we would of course limit it to forward iterators) It may need an extra `+m_primitives.size()`, I haven't looked much.

Comment: I update test, I think is not a good choice for std::vector push_back    when primitvies big(if not pre allcate)

Comment: I think the assumptions are: 1) debug mode speed is not relevant, 2) filling this vector takes a negligible amount of time compared to the rest of a useful program. Still, I guess adding a call to reserve would be nice (if the abstraction permits it).

Comment: Thank you for reply, In release mode, It can accept, But In debug mode, It can't accept(Almost take 10 minutes). Sometimes need to debug the program.

Comment: And doesn't the same phenomenon (explosion of the runtime in debug mode) also affect the rest of your program, which would then take days to execute and those 10 minutes would remain negligible?